# Cancel macOS logout

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript

Users often forget to do a task which must be done before logging out. To help with this I'd like to create a popup on logout with an option to cancel logging off.

I'm open to using any language. AppleScript looks promising, although I have no idea how to go about detecting and canceling a logout.

Since writing the question I've discovered the quit handler fires on logging out. I've created a script showing a dialog in the quit handler, which does the job of cancelling a logout, but I'm left with an ugly icon in the dock.

I'm able to remove the dock icon using the "LSUIElement" property in "info.plist", however it no longer prevents logging out when this is set.

Comment: If the ugly dock icon is a problem, that can easily be fixed by saving the AppleScript as an app and then changing the icon?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, logout clean-up is handled by individual apps: e.g., a document-based app with unsaved changes might prompt the user to save documents first. That makes sense, because each app knows what does and does not need to be taken care of before it closes, while the system generally doesn't.

As you've discovered, if you create a front-facing app the system will poll it and give the app a chance to delay or abort logout. The system does not notify background apps, services, or accessories (on the assumption that only user input needs to be checked for persistence). If you set LSUIElement to 1, your app becomes a background app, and never gets the chance to interfere with logout. There's no easy or immediate way both to have such an app *work* and have it *be invisible* to the dock.

Maybe if you're more specific about what your goal is, there might be a workaround (e.g., if you're only interested in monitoring a specific app, that might be doable).